# Which way should I choose between WorkManager and Handler when I run a task periodically?

Tags: android, kotlin

In the application’s life-cycle, I hope to get the `maxAmplitude` of `MediaRecorder` every 100ms just like Code A

I have read the article both [this one](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager?gclid=Cj0KCQiA_8OPBhDtARIsAKQu0gYoFOvEUegMz8G3w3_faD0pMf9-P_c_5yy6IqF2yCvH4ucgbukPansaArIjEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) and [that one](https://medium.com/android-news/schedule-tasks-and-jobs-intelligently-in-android-e0b0d9201777)

I was told that

*WorkManager is the primary recommended API for background processing. Scheduled tasks that start at a later time and can run periodically*

and

*When application is running and we want to schedule or run a task at a specific time then it is recommended to use Handler class in conjunction with Timer and Thread. Instead of using Alarm Manger, Job Scheduler etc. it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.*

1: Which way should I choose between `WorkManager` and `Handler` when I run a task periodically ?

2: And more, is `Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask{ })` good way?

**Code A**

```
private fun getAmplitude(): Int {
        var result = 0
        mRecorder?.let {
            result = it.maxAmplitude
        }     
        return result
}
```

Comment: `WorkManager is the primary recommended API for background processing.` if this isn't background processing, you probably don't need to use workmanager, but i doubt it will make much of a difference either way, you could probably use either one and it would be fine

Comment: You can use workmanager wile the app is running, and you can listen in on the work using livedata